# loop over aws provider to create ressources in every aws account

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects in Terraform called users and the structure is the following:

```
variable "accounts" {
  type = list(object({
    id       = string #used in assume_role
    email   = string
    is_enabled = bool
  }))
}
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to create a simple S3 bucket in each of those AWS accounts (if the is_enabled is true). I was able to do it for a single account but I am not sure if there is a way to loop over a provider?

**Code for a single account - main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "new_account"
  region = "eu-west-3"

  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.this.id}:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
    session_name = "new_account_creation"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  provider = aws.new_account

  bucket = "new-account-bucket-${aws_organizations_account.this.id}"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

Comment: You could instead put the provider and the bucket into a folder / module and then loop over the module. Modules support for_each / count.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define one provider for each aws account you want to use:

1. Create a module (*i.e.* a directory), where your bucket configuration lives:

```
    ├── main.tf
    └── module
        └── bucket.tf
```

1. `bucket.tf` should contain the resource definition: `resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {...}`
2. In `main.tf` , define multiple aws providers and call the module with each of them:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "account1"
  region = "eu-west-1"
  ...
}
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "account2"
  region = "us-west-1"
  ...
}

module "my_module" {
  source = "./module"
  providers = {
    aws.account1 = aws.account1
    aws.account2 = aws.account2
  }
}
```

I guess you could also get fancy by creating a variable containing the providers, and pass it to the module invocation (you could probably also use a filter on the list to take into account the `is_enabled` flag)

More details about providers: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. My issue is I all my aws accounts are stored in my list and I don't know the exact number of accounts as well

Answer (score -5):

Found what I was looking for here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19932

Thanks Bryan Karaffa

```
## Just some data... a list(map())
locals {
  aws_accounts = [
    { "aws_account_id": "123456789012", "foo_value": "foo",    "bar_value": "bar"    },
    { "aws_account_id": "987654321098", "foo_value": "foofoo", "bar_value": "barbar" },
    ]
}
## Here's the proposed magic... `provider.for_each`
provider "aws" {
  for_each = local.aws_accounts
  alias = each.value.aws_account_id
  assume_role {
    role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::${each.value.aws_account_id}:role/TerraformAccessRole"
  }
}
## Modules reference the provider dynamically using `each.value.aws_account_id`
module "foo" {
  source = "./foo"
  for_each = local.aws_accounts
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.${each.value.aws_account_id}"
  }
  foo = each.value.foo_value
}
module "bar" {
  source = "./bar"
  for_each = local.aws_accounts
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.${each.value.aws_account_id}"
  }
  bar = each.value.bar_value
}
```

Comment: did not work for me - terraform failed on me complaining that the alias was not in the proper format, though I literally copied this answer. The official help advises to extract the resources to be looped through as a submodule and call this sub module as many times as you need.

Comment: This code have not been tested, was it ? It is suggested by a user at what would be nice, not something supported